# Would efficient Bulletproofs for CT increase transaction sizes? By how much?

Tags: confidential-transactions, zero-knowledge

Ignoring that it would be a hard fork, if Bitcoin implemented confidential transactions using [Bulletproofs](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/1066.pdf) -- how much would an average transaction increase *estimated* in bytes?

(Just looking for a simple guesstimate here)